# Telerik Net Core Treeview Template-Get value from inputbox of selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telerik, kendo-treeview

How could I get the value from an `inputbox` of a selected `checkboxitem`(and `subitems`)?
I can get the label of a checkedItem(`item.Name`), but I don't now how to get the value of an `inputbox`.

```
<script id="treeview_distribute_template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td width="500px;">
    #= item.Name # &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td >
    <input id='comment_input' type='text' style="width:500px;" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </script>

function getCheckedNodes(nodes) {
        var node, childCheckedNodes;
        var checkedNodes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            node = nodes[i];
            if (node.checked) {
                checkedNodes.push(node);
            }
            if (node.hasChildren) {
                childCheckedNodes = getCheckedNodes(node.children.view());
                if (childCheckedNodes.length > 0) {
                    checkedNodes = checkedNodes.concat(childCheckedNodes);
                }
            }
        }
        return checkedNodes;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: In this [link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/get-selected-node-databound-item-id),Constantine added the answer `var data = $('treeview').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.node);` may help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SOLVED:    
 var inputValues = [];          
       function onCheck(e) {
        var checkedNodes = [];
        var treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
        var node = e.node;
        var val = $(node).find('input.comment_input').val();
        var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(e.node);
        getCheckedNodesText(dataItem,  val)

        if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {
            message = "IDs of checked nodes: " + checkedNodes.join(",");
        } else {
            message = "No nodes checked.";
        }

        $("#selected-count").html(message);
    }

    function removeFromArray(array, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].departmentId == value)
                array.splice(i, 1);
        }
        return array;
    }

    function getCheckedNodesText(nodes, checkedNodeText) {
        if (nodes.checked) {
            inputValues.push({ departmentId: nodes.id, value: checkedNodeText });
        }
        else {
            inputValues = removeFromArray(inputValues, nodes.id);
        }

    }

function actionOK(e) {
    treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var checkedNodes = getCheckedItems(treeView);
    var node = e.node;
    updateResult(checkedNodes);
    $.ajax
       (
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("Distribute", "Document")',
                data: { 'selectedItems': JSON.stringify(checkedNodes), 'idDoc': document.getElementById("SelectedDocId").value, 'notes': JSON.stringify(inputValues) },
                                type: 'POST',
                                     success: function (responce)
                                     {

                                     },
            }
        );
}
```